# JSON encode con consulta SQL y PHP

Tags: php, json

Buenas a todos. Esta pregunta ya la he visto en varios temas pero no entiendo muy bien cual es el problema de porque no introduce los resultados  en un array. Se que la consulta devuelve resultados.

Dejo código:

```
function jsonEcho(){
include('conn.php');
$servername = "localhost";


$ttenQ="SELECT `id`, `nombre_cock`, `categoria_fk`, `descripcion`,`Preparacion`, `img_path`, `puntuacion` FROM `def_cockteles`  ORDER BY `puntuacion` DESC LIMIT 10";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$ttenQ);

$topTen = array();

$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
printf("Result set has %d rows.\n",$rowcount);
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {

    $topTen[]=array('ruta'=> $row["img_path"],'descripcion'=>$row["descripcion"]);
}

 return json_encode($topTen);
}

print_r(jsonEcho());

?>
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error?

Comment: No devuelve el JSON

Comment: Quizas invirtiendo el `inlcude` con la variable `$servername = "localhost";`

Comment: Perdón, $servername no aparece en el código, fue en error mio copiandolo. La información de la conexión esta en el archivo incluido.

Answer (score 1):

Reemplaza el return por echo y listo, con eso te mostrara el json.

```
echo json_encode($topTen);
```

Saludos

Comment: Nada, sigue sin devolver resultados

Comment: Me parece extraño, estas seguro que tu consulta arroja resultados? Has ido colocando var_dump en todo el codigo hasta que retorne resultados, porque si no te lo muestra, puede que sea el retorno que este incorrecto, es decir, que el arreglo no tenga datos que retornar. Por cierto, si vas a incluir N veces un archivo, es mejor que le pongas include_once, lo otro, si abres una conexion con la BD, debes cerrarla.

Answer (score 0):

si lo esta haciendo con **ajax** tienes que comentar esta línea `printf("Result set has %d rows.\n",$rowcount);`y si quieres ver el resultado de esa línea de código sería bueno que la pogan el arreglo también. Cuando haces una petición **ajax**, lo correcto es que sólo se imprima el `json_encode`. Prueba este código:

```
$topTen = array();

$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
$topTen['rowcount'] = "Result set has $rowcount rows.\n";
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {    
    $topTen['data'][]=array('ruta'=> $row["img_path"],'descripcion'=>$row["descripcion"]);
}
return json_encode($topTen);
```

Comment: Sigue sin devolverme el JSON... no se que puede estar pasando. La petición la estoy haciendo con objective-C, aun así tengo un visor de JSON y tampoco me presenta nada

Comment: me puede mostrar que te devuelve ?

Comment: No devuelve absolutamente nada.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba estableciendo la cabecera **Content-Type**:

```
<?php
$data = /** lo que sea que necesitas serializar **/;
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Respuesta original:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script

Answer (score 0):

Prueba:

```
$topTen = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
  $topTen[] = $row;
}
print json_encode($topTen);
```

y quita el printf